# iOS - converting a date received from a mySQL server into users local time

Tags: mysql, objective-c, timezone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a server which stores the times of data sent between users on a mySQL database using NOW() to set the time.
I am trying to convert the time to the recipient's local time, but not having much luck (I would convert the time before storing, but as I say I want the time to be local to the recipient, not the sender).
The date is returned to the app as a string, and I have tried to adjust it as follows:

```
NSString *string1 = [[receivedMessages objectAtIndex:thisRow]objectAtIndex:2];
NSDate *messageDate; 
NSCalendar* cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar;
NSTimeZone* tz = cal.timeZone;   

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM dd yyyy hh:mma"];
[formatter setTimeZone:tz];

messageDate = [formatter dateFromString:string1];
```

It does kind of format the date, but not correctly. A date that is received by the app as:

```
April 5 2012 5:49AM
```

is converted to:

```
2012-04-05 04:49:00 +0000
```

I'm wondering how xcode works out which time zone the date belonged to in the first place?

Actually, I've just tested it again using

```
NSTimeZone *pst = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"PST"];
```

in place of

```
 NSCalendar* cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar;
 NSTimeZone* tz = cal.timeZone;
```

and it still gives me the time as 2012-04-05 04:49:00 +0000.

Anyone have any ideas?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-CJBGJDAE), `messageDate = [formatter dateFromString:string1];` will return an NSDate. When you are displaying the results, you are printing an NSDate object which (I'm guessing) is 'stringified' to an [ISO 8601 date](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). These NSDate objects are normalized to an absolute time (without timezone information).

Once you have the date object, just go one step further and format the output. I'm guessing the tz you show is for the original time, so this is fine (`dateFromString` will convert to 'absolute time'). All you need to add is something like [localizedStringFromDate:dateStyle:timeStyle:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-SW52) to get the time locally.

```
//If this is not in UTC, we don't have any knowledge about
//which tz it is. MUST BE IN UTC.
dateString = "2012-03-12 9:53:23"

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM dd yyyy hh:mma"];

NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSString *result = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:date dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

//The result should be in MY timezone automatically.
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you entirely. It might be easier for me to explain how it works at the moment. When a user sends their data, the time recorded is the time on the server - which is GMT. But if the sender is in New York and the recipient is in Tokyo, then GMT is no good for the recipient, nor is the time in NYC. So I need to convert the GMT time provided to the users local time - but I don't see how localizedStringFromDate would do that. As far as I can tell it's just for formatting the structure of the date - not changing its values? Or have I misunderstood how to use it?

Comment: When you retrieve the date from the server, what is it's format? String ISO 8601: `2012-02-28T09:13:23Z`, Regular string: `April 5 2012 12:34AM`, POSIX: `123582342`?

Comment: It looks exactly like this: 2012-04-05 16:14:00, looks most like the IOS 8601 version, but I don't have any T's or Z's in there

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing the specifics of how the dates are stored, but the upshot is that dates should be _stored_ in absolute time. ISO 8601 dates for example, are usually stored as [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC) or offsets of UTC. If you know the date in the DB is absolute, you don't have to worry about the sender's tz. You just have to format the 'absolute' date in the locale of the receiver. I'll update my post with example code.

Comment: Ok I think I get it, I just tried to change my code to resemble your example (had to reaarange the setDateFormat but only to get it the way I want it). Seems to be working now, since GMT and UTC are the same (as far as I know). Thanks a lot :-)